# How to finally submit a text string from an input box type=number?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I send the value shown in an HTML input box as '030.34' and not '0.34'?
I need to prepend '03'for an ID.

I need the input box to be type 'number' so the up down buttons can be used, so I cannot set it to text.

Added: there are limits max min set on the input.

Any ideas?
Thanks Chris

```js
function ipFunction() {
  var c = SETPOINT.value;
  SETPOINT.value = xxx + c; // prepend '03' HOW???
  return true; // can be submitted 
}
```

```html
<form id="frmSetPoint" name="frmSetPoint" action="#" onsubmit="ipFunction()" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="number" onkeydown="return false" id="SETPOINT" name="SETPOINT" min="1" max="10">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Value">
</form>
```

Comment: can you not just place the `'03'` where your `xxx` is?

Comment: There are limits max min set on the number input, so it wont submit. Thanks.

Comment: then you need to edit your question and create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem as the way it is worded and with the code provided, you would only have to swap the xxx and 03

Comment: What do you mean with "won't submit"?

Comment: `return true; // can be submitted` - can also be submitted without that ... If you use "old-school" event handling via HTML attributes, then you need `onsubmit="return ipFunction()"`, if you want the true/false return value of the function to actually allow or forbid submission of the form.

Comment: You can not "store" arbitrary text into a number input field, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#validation Just grab the value, and write it with the prefix into a hidden field ...

Comment: Thanks, but there were all sorts of problems with the max,min,step attributes

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day on this - I'm just learning - but a friend put me right.
Hopefully this should help others.

```
$("#frmSetPoint").validate({
       submitHandler: function (form) {
 var serializedData = $(form).serialize();
     serializedData = serializedData.replace("=", "='P03") + "'";

                    $.ajax({

                        url: '/value.cgi',

                        data: serializedData,

                        type: 'GET',

                        success: function (data) {                

},

  error: function (data) {
                                              
$(currentButton).prop('disabled', false);
$(currentButton).css({
color: '#ffffff',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                          
backgroundColor: '#00FF00'
});
}
});

return false;
}
}); //validate
```